# Is there an efficient way to find a string fulfilling given regex?

Tags: regex

Let's say I've got such regex (python notation) `r'^namespace/(\w+)/([0-9]+)/'`, is there a way to reverse this regex and find a string fulfilling it?

By reversing **I don't mean** manual constructing `'namespace/' + 'a_1' + '/' + '1'`, **but** systematic way to reverse **any regular expression** consisting of **some special characters**. So that for every regex I can generate (any) string fulfilling it.

The only thing that comes to my mind is to parse the given regex with some other regexs, but it does not seem acceptable solution. Although I expect the whole operation to have huge complexity, I still look for at least a bit more sophisticated way to do it.

Comment: Can you provide some example matches

Comment: @anubhava I need any match. But the problem is any match for **any regex**. There are many different unspecified regexs, for every single one of them I need to find any string matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The only thing that comes to my mind is to parse the given regex with some other regexs, but it does not seem acceptable solution

You don't need to parse the regex with regexes, but yes you will need to parse it. When you have an AST of the regular expression, you can easily traverse that and build a possible match in linear time (for plain regular expression, nothing too fancy like lookaround).

Check [Enumerating Regular Languages](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?EnumeratingRegularLanguages) for an example code and continuative links.

Comment: I need a while to dig deeper into it, but it looks like this is the thing I search for:)